# write_xlsx from the writexl library doesn't display the name of the rows in R

Tags: r, excel, statistics, display

I am trying to make descriptive statistics table using the basicStats function from fBasics library.
Code is as follows.

```
sum_desc_stat=basicStats(sum_stat)
sum_desc_stat
write_xlsx(sum_desc_stat,'C:/Users/sum_desc_stat.xlsx')
```

If I run this in R, it shows me the names of the rows like Nobs, Mean, SD, etc. However, if I save that as Excel file, I can't see any of the rownames.
Can anyone help me how to display the rownames in Excel file as well?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: See if `tibble::rownames_to_column()` function solves your problem.